# Unable to loop in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to do a simple looping using .map but not getting the expected output. Here is my code -

```
const filters = [this.state.filterAttributes ] //[Part Number, Product Line]

<tr key = {key}>

    {filters.map((k) => {

        return <th>{k}</th>
    })}

    <td>{item.PartNumber}</td>
    <td>{item.productline}</td>
</tr>
```

The `th{k}` is returning as `<th>Part NumberProduct Line</th>` instead of

```
<th>Part Number</th>
<th>Product Line</th>
```

Can any one please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of the following line :

```
const filters = [this.state.filterAttributes] //[Part Number, Product Line]
```

Now, `filters` will have the following value :

```
[[this.state.filterAttributes]]
```

```js
const a = ['Part Number', 'Product Line']
const filters = [a]

console.log(filters)
```

What you tried to do to copy your array should be the following, using the deconstructing operator :

```
const filters = [...this.state.filterAttributes]
```

```js
const a = ['Part Number', 'Product Line']
const filters = [...a]

console.log(filters)
```

Also, here is a shorter syntax for your `map` rendering :

```
{filters.map(k => <th key={k}>{k}</th>)} //Do not forget the key
```

You could also extract the value out of your state instead of copying it by using the deconstruction :

```
const { filterAttributes } = this.state

<tr key={key}>

    {filterAttribute.map(k => <th key={k}>{k}</th>)}

    <td>{item.PartNumber}</td>
    <td>{item.productline}</td>
</tr>
```